# CSS 3 Skew serrilhado no Chrome

Tags: css, css3

Ao utilizar a propriedade transform: skew(valor) em browsers webkit ele apresenta um certo serrilhado onde fica com angulo:

```
-webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
-moz-transform: skew(20deg);
-ms-transform: skew(20deg);
transform: skew(20deg);
```

Existe alguma propriedade específica pra "consertar" isso?

Comment: Usei bem a cabeça e me veio o código: -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; que resolveu meu problema. Vou fechar  pergunta obrigado : )

Comment: Boa tarde dsantoro, poste isto como resposta, pode ser útil a outras pessoas. Não precisa fechar é só responder :)

Comment: Valeu a dica Guilherme.

Answer (score 1):

Usei bem a cabeça e me veio o código: `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` que resolveu meu problema.